# Adding Unit Tests that run on device to Existing Xcode 4 Project

Tags: unit-testing, xcode4

I'm trying to add unit tests to an existing universal app in Xcode 4.  I've followed the tutorials and while the logic tests run fine in the simulator, when I try to test on device I get a dialog saying "Logic Testing on iOS devices is not supported.  You can run logic tests on the Simulator."  However, I've noticed that when you create a new project in Xcode 4 and check the Include Unit Tests box, it will actually install and run the tests on device.  Am I missing an option somewhere that would allow me enable that on my existing project?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think I figured it out by going line by line through the Build Settings for the Cocoa Touch Unit Testing Bundle.

**Build Settings**

*Linker*

- Set Bundle Loader to `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/[Your App Name].app/[YourAppName]`

*Unit Testing*

- Set Test Host to `$(BUNDLE_LOADER)`

**Build Phases**

Add the application target to the Target Dependencies.

Once you do all that, you can just hook up your device and hit Test.

Comment: more info http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/

Comment: Joe, may be you know how to add Logic tests? Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781589/adding-logic-tests-to-the-project-in-xcode-4-5

Comment: I followed this and it did not work right away, but after browsing SO for awhile, I found out a few more steps that made this answer work. I had to quit Xcode, delete the derived data folder for my app, reopen xcode, clean it, create a new scheme, then run on that scheme and it worked. Thanks for the solution Jose!