# Adding Logic Tests to the project in Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I'm using xcode 4.5 and trying to add logic tests to the project. (This is actually a test, newly created project without unit tests). I'm following this guide:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html
So, what i've done so far:

1. Created a new project (View Based Application template)
2. Click on File -> New- CocoaTouchUnitTestBundle
   That's it. The tests (as documentation states) are ready to use.
   But I have the following problems:
   The SenTestinKit.framework appears in red
   [image]

If I press Test button issue navigator shows nothing:
[image]

If I select another debugger here(LLDB by default, trying to select GDB):

[image]

Xcode just hangs out:
[image]

P.S I also tried to remove SenTestingKit.framework (which is in red) and add new. Nothing changed.

What am I doing wrong ?? I suppose to see something like this(screenshot from apple guide):
[image]

Any help will be greatly appriciated!

Answer (score -1):

Actually, your code works now.

I don't know why Xcode didn't initially add the SenTestingKit framework in correctly when you created the test bundle.

But now the code, "testExample" which was auto-generated for you, is running, and it is telling you to add in some real tests, by giving you an error. That's what STFail does.

So, if you take out that line, and start writing your own tests, you should be fine.

Comment: So you have xcode 4.5 and you repeated all steps and it works fine, right?

Comment: What have you done? Created a new project WITHOUT tests and added them later? Please tell me whats's in your Budle Loader and Test Host(I mean - logicTestTarget -> Builed Settings -> Linking and Unit Testing sections) ?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't read close enough. I thought the screen-shot was YOUR screenshot, not Apple's. But I did do the same things as you. I added the library back into the project, and it did link, and get to the runtime error.

Comment: I try to understand is the problem in my xcode or smth. please answer my question in comment above. I mean do you create LOGIC tests or APPLICATION. Because application tests work fine.....

Comment: @Kev♦ did you read carefully the given answer and the comments below? This guy mistakenly decide that my problem was solved already. So it's NOT an answer at all. Unfortunately....